# check if values of a column are in values of another (numpy array)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a numpy array and I want to create a new one appending the row only if for each row, the element in the columnX is absent in every row of the columnY.

I thought about a for loop to do it, but it doesn't work.

```
array = [()]
for row in data:
    if data[:, 0] == data[:, 6]:
         np.append(array, row)
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: The question is confusing. The needs are not clear. Please clarify the problem and put a small sample of the inputs and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said numpy but it is this easy in pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[x,y])
df = df[~df.x.isin(df.y)]
output = df.values # back to numpy
```

Comment: I know it is, but I need to do it using numpy. Any advice?

Comment: Bummer, numpy has an isin as well, but im less familiar with it and not at a computer to test it.  If someone else doesnt chime in with a numpy solution, I'll respond later

Comment: thank you, I was able to do it using the numpy.isin() method :)

Answer (score -1):

Guess from @Jordan's answer, the resulting array should be like:

```
array = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [5, 6], [4, 3]])
array[~np.isin(array[:, 0], array[:, 1])]
```

and get

```
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6]])
```

I'm not sure if I get the point of your question.